# Add class on product list after successfully added to cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi Guys need some help...

```
<ul>
<li class="product">product details + add to cart button</li>
<li class="product">product details + add to cart button</li>
<li class="product">product details + add to cart button</li>
</ul>
```

What I need is when I successfully added a product to cart it will add a class (added) to the `<li>` element automatically so that the styling will be implemented.

```
<ul>
<li class="product added">product details + add to cart button</li>
<li class="product">product details + add to cart button</li>
<li class="product">product details + add to cart button</li>
</ul>
```

Got this function from the net and I don't know what to do

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart' );
function trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                //code here
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: you will need some ajax and some php with what you have

Comment: yes, I think this is hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('.product').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('added');
       // Adding product to cart...etc    
     });
```

Comment: I don't think so, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qugrhp7z/4/ 
Once you click on li inspect the element with your browser you'll notice the class "added" added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart' );
    function trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart() {

       foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function($){
                        alert('dsfdssdfsdsd')
                        $(".post-<?php echo $product_id; ?>").addClass('cart-added-class');

                    })(jQuery);
                </script>
            <?php

      }
}
```